# How is a question able to be closed by just two people?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

Simple question, how [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225530/how-does-thanos-know-how-to-use-the-infinity-stones) question able to be closed by just two people?

Comment: See also [The Dawn of Dupehammers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers)

Answer (score 13):

User [TheLethalCarrot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot) has a gold tag badge in that tag. Gold Tag holders can close a duplicate on their own.

> [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders)
>
> "*You can instantly close as a duplicate any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.*"

[image]

and if you hover over the gold badge, you'll be provided with an explanation of its meaning.

[image]

Comment: Minor thing to add, there are some limitations. Users are limited in their ability to dupehammer, for example, if they've changed tags (presumably to keep people from retagging a question to their gold-badge target, and instantly closing it, whether or not it fit that tag).